# Como resolver erro de renderização do Highcharts no Internet Explorer?

Tags: highcharts, internet-explorer-9

Estou tendo problemas com um gráfico do Highcharts no Internet Explorer (testei as versões 9 e 11). O mesmo gráfico é exibido sem erros no Firefox e no Chrome.

Vejam o problema abaixo:

[image: Gráfico não é completamente exibido no IE 11]

Reparei que o problema ocorre quando tenho uma quantidade grande de dados para exibir na tela. Cada grupo de dados (datas, série A, série B, série C) tem, aproximadamente, 8 mil registros (são dados de 5 em 5min do dia 15/09 ao dia 15/10). Reparei também que os pontos estão lá, mesmo no IE, porém as linhas param de ser renderizadas inesperadamente.

Se eu diminuo a quantidade de dados, pegando outro período, por exemplo, o gráfico é exibido sem problemas no IE:

[image: Exibido sem erros no IE]

Segue meu código:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
        var intervaloDatas = '<%= intervaloDatasSplit %>';
        var intervaloGrandezaA = '<%= intervaloGrandezaASplit %>';
        var intervaloGrandezaB = '<%= intervaloGrandezaBSplit %>';
        var intervaloGrandezaC = '<%= intervaloGrandezaCSplit %>';

        var labelCanalA = 'Kw';
        var labelCanalB = 'kVar Ind';
        var labelCanalC = 'kVAr Cap';
        var cliente = '949085';

        var seriesOne = new Array();
        seriesOne = intervaloDatas.split(',');

        var seriesA = new Array();
        seriesA = intervaloGrandezaA.split(',');
        var seriesB = new Array();
        seriesB = intervaloGrandezaB.split(',');
        var seriesC = new Array();
        seriesC = intervaloGrandezaC.split(',');

        var dataA = new Array(seriesOne.length);
        var dataB = new Array(seriesOne.length);
        var dataC = new Array(seriesOne.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < seriesOne.length; i++) {

            dataA[i] = new Array(2);
            dataA[i][0] = Date.parse(seriesOne[i]);
            dataA[i][1] = parseFloat(seriesA[i]);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < seriesOne.length; i++) {

            dataB[i] = new Array(2);
            dataB[i][0] = Date.parse(seriesOne[i]);
            dataB[i][1] = parseFloat(seriesB[i]);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < seriesOne.length; i++) {

            dataC[i] = new Array(2);
            dataC[i][0] = Date.parse(seriesOne[i]);
            dataC[i][1] = parseFloat(seriesC[i]);
        }

        Highcharts.setOptions({
            lang: {
                months: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
                shortMonths: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
                weekdays: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
                loading: ['Atualizando o gráfico...aguarde'],
                contextButtonTitle: 'Exportar gráfico',
                decimalPoint: ',',
                thousandsSep: '.',
                downloadJPEG: 'Baixar imagem JPEG',
                downloadPDF: 'Baixar arquivo PDF',
                downloadPNG: 'Baixar imagem PNG',
                downloadSVG: 'Baixar vetor SVG',
                printChart: 'Imprimir gráfico',
                rangeSelectorFrom: 'De',
                rangeSelectorTo: 'Para',
                rangeSelectorZoom: 'Zoom',
                resetZoom: 'Limpar Zoom',
                resetZoomTitle: 'Voltar Zoom para nível 1:1'
            }
        });

        $('#container').highcharts({

            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x',
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderRadius: 20,
                plotBorderColor: "DodgerBlue"
            },
            credits:
                {
                    enabled: false
                },
            exporting: {
                buttons: {
                    contextButtons: {
                        enabled: false,
                        menuItems: null
                    }
                },
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Curva de Carga - Cliente: ' + cliente
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    month: '%e. %b',
                    year: '%b'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                text: null
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: {
                            x1: 0,
                            y1: 0,
                            x2: 0,
                            y2: 1
                        },
                        stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                    },
                    marker: {
                        radius: 2
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }
            },

            series: [{
                type: 'line',
                name: labelCanalA,
                data: dataA,
                color: "#008000"
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                name: labelCanalB,
                data: dataB,
                color: "#0000FF"
            },
             {
                 type: 'line',
                 name: labelCanalC,
                 data: dataC,
                 color: "#FF0000"
             }]
        });
    });

</script>
```

Os dados estão sendo enviados pelo code behind, no formato abaixo:

```
public String intervaloDatasSplit { get; set; }
public String intervaloGrandezaASplit { get; set; }
public String intervaloGrandezaBSplit { get; set; }
public String intervaloGrandezaCSplit { get; set; }

intervaloDatasSplit = "9/16/2015 12:50:00 AM,9/16/2015 12:55:00 AM,9/16/2015 1:00:00 AM";
intervaloGrandezaASplit = "12.67,12.96,11.81";
intervaloGrandezaBSplit = "5.18,4.9,4.9";
intervaloGrandezaCSplit = "0,0,0";
```

Obs.: Estou informando apenas os 3 primeiros dados de cada intervalo para fins ilustrativos.

Alguém já passou por algo parecido?